# Vignette V8 Upgrade

Tags: content-management-system, vignette

Vignette upgrades are usually not straightforward. You basically have to do a new installation and migrate over all of your customizations etc. Does anyone know if the upcoming V8 version is easier to upgrade or if its easier to upgrade from a certain previous version compared to earlier version. So I can upgrade to an earlier version (say 7.6) and then hopefully its easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer. You do need to upgrade to 7.6 before upgrading to 8.0 from an earlier version.

Comment: FYI - They will generally come out with a "skip level" upgrade package after the release.

Comment: Yeah maybe. But it always depends on what version you're upgrading from. If from something thats older then the skip level upgrade may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Vignette v8 is officially not out yet, its only been soft released to some selected clients. My guess is that the upgrade will not be very straightforward but I've no concrete information on that.

During the wait you might also be interested in an open source alternative of Vignette v8 freely available: Sense/Net 6.0 http://blog.sensenet.hu/post/2009/08/05/An-Open-Source-Alternative-for-Vignette-v8.aspx